# Is this property of expectation true?

Tags: expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables and $Z = f(X,Y)$ for some function $f$. Additionally, let $g(\cdot)$ be a different function of $X$ and $Y$. Is the following true?
$$
E_Z[g(X,Y)] = E_{XY}[g(X,Y)]
$$
or equivalently, if $\mathcal X, \mathcal Y,$ and $\mathcal Z$ are the ranges of $X,Y,$ and $Z$ respectively (I'm aware that the integration on the left-hand side of the equation below does not make much sense, as $g(x,y)$ can be taken out of the integration, but I'm not sure if there's a better way of stating what I mean),
$$
\int_{\mathcal Z} g(x,y) p_Z(z) dz = \int_{\mathcal X} \int_{\mathcal Y} g(x,y) p_{XY}(x,y) dx dy
$$
I think this statement is true, as
\begin{align}
E_Z[g(X,Y)] &= E_{XY}[E_Z[g(X,Y) \mid X,Y]] \\
&= E_{XY}[g(X,Y)]
\end{align}

Comment: What do notations "$E_Z$" and "$E_{XY}$" mean? There is no need to attach a random variable to the expectation operator (though I do see this sometimes in the literature):  this is because, if $X, Y, Z$ are all defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, then by definition, $E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) P(d\omega), E[Z] = E[g(X, Y)] = \int_\Omega g(X(\omega), Y(\omega))P(d\omega)$, either $X$ or $Z$ are simply integrands (functions), while "$E$" should be interpreted as a shorthand for the integration operator.

Comment: If you tried to use $E_Z[X]$ to mean the conditional expectation $E[X|Z]$, then this is non-standard. The standard notation $E[X|Z]$ is succinct and clear already.  It is pointless to create a new system for conditional expectation.

Comment: @Zhanxiong sorry, I should've been clearer with my notation. I've edited my question with what $E_Z$ and $E_{XY}$ mean.

Comment: The left hand side of your expectation makes no sense because the arguments $x$ and $y$ of the integrand $g$ are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to check if (see my comments below your question)
\begin{align}
E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)] = E[g(X, Y)|X, Y] = g(X, Y)
\end{align}
is true.

This is not true.  A simple counterexample is: let $X, Y \text{ i.i.d.} \sim N(0, 1)$, $f(X, Y) = X + Y$, $g(X, Y) = X - Y$.  It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625714/are-the-random-variables-x-y-and-x-y-independent-if-x-y-are-distribut/1625748#1625748) that $f(X, Y)$
and $g(X, Y)$ are independent, whence
\begin{align}
E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)] = E[g(X, Y)] = 0 \neq g(X, Y) = X - Y.
\end{align}

Another way to disprove your conjecture is by noting that $E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)]$ has to be a function of $f(X, Y)$, say $h(f(X, Y))$, then you are requiring $(h \circ f)(X, Y) = g(X, Y)$, which is not true unless $g = h \circ f$.  This is in general very unlikely.

It seems that your argument tries to apply the tower property of the conditional expectation: if $\mathscr{F}_1 \subset \mathscr{F}_2 \subset \mathscr{F}$, then
\begin{align}
E[X|\mathscr{F}_1] = E[E[X|\mathscr{F}_2]|\mathscr{F}_1] 
= E[E[X|\mathscr{F}_1]|\mathscr{F}_2]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
While $\sigma(f(X, Y))$ ("$\mathscr{F}_1$") is indeed a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\sigma(X, Y)$ ("$\mathscr{F}_2$"), the problem lies in that neither $E[g(X, Y)|X, Y]$ is $\sigma(f(X, Y))$-measurable (if you want to use the first equality in $(1)$) nor $E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)]$ is equal to $g(X, Y)$ (if you want to use the second equality in $(1)$).

Comment: In your statement $$E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)] = E[g(X, Y)|X, Y] = g(X, Y)$$ I only conjecture that the second equality is true, $$E[g(X, Y)|X, Y] = g(X, Y)$$ and not the first equality, $$E[g(X, Y)|f(X, Y)] = E[g(X, Y)|X, Y]$$ I'm not familiar with the measure-theoretic foundations of probability, so could you please explain how the second equality in your statement is disproven in your answer?

Comment: @mhdadk The second equality is true. If you only conjectured the second equality, then $f(X, Y)$ plays no role and should be removed for clarity.

Comment: But what I wrote in my attempt at a proof is $$E_{XY}[E_Z[g(X,Y) \mid X,Y]] = E_{XY}[g(X,Y)]$$ I didn't write $$E_{XY}[E_Z[g(X,Y) \mid f(X,Y)]] = E_{XY}[g(X,Y)]$$ Is this what you meant?

Comment: @mhdadk Again, I couldn't understand your notations "$E_{XY}, E_Z$" (even with your updated question), they make no sense to me.  My last comment responds to your first comment, where you asked me to explain why "$E[g(X, Y)|X, Y] = g(X, Y)$".

Comment: After your editing, it becomes more ambiguous to me.  Can you simply clarify: is what you conjectured an equality of the unconditional expectation (i.e., the common-sense expectation) or the conditional expectation?

Comment: It looks like what you conjectured is similar to the [law of unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), but in this theorem, $f$ must be equal to $g$, in which case $\int zp_Z(z)dz = \int g(x, y)p_{X, Y}(x, y)dxdy$ indeed holds.

Comment: Then it seems that I’ve made a mistake somewhere in my question. To be honest, I originally asked this question as a simpler version of a more complicated one, but it seems I oversimplified. If you are interested, and have the time, I’ve asked the more complicated question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/604582/296197).