# Is a nested expectation equivalent to expectation on the joint? $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\mathbb{E}_{p(y \mid x)}[f(x, y)]] = \mathbb{E}_{p(x, y)}[f(x, y)]$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

Is it always true that nested expectations equal expectations on the joint?
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\mathbb{E}_{p(y \mid x)}[f(x, y)]] = \mathbb{E}_{p(x, y)}[f(x, y)]
$$
Something along these lines appears at the end of a proof I am reading. Surely though one can write the LHS using the TOWER property which would give
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(y)}[f(x, y)]
$$
which seems quite different..

Comment: Research Fubini's Theorem.  Alternatively, examine whatever definition of conditional expectation you are familiar with (this *is* one definition).

Comment: By Fubini's I know I can exchange integrals. I'm assuming I need to decompose it as such?
$$
\int f(x, y) p(x, y) = \int f(x, y) p(y \mid x) p(x) = \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\mathbb{E}_{p(y\mid x}[f(x, y)]]
$$

Comment: Fubini's Theorem also asserts the sequential integrals equal the joint integral, under mild conditions on the integrand.

Comment: As I argued in answers and comments of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604582/how-can-i-re-write-the-expectation-for-a-linear-quadratic-gaussian-problem) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604523/is-this-property-of-expectation-true), it is really pointless and potentially inaccurate to attach subscripts to the expectation operator "$E$". When written in standard notations, I infer what you tried to confirm is 
\begin{align}
E[E[f(X, Y)|X]] = E[f(X, Y)], 
\end{align}
which is exactly the law of iterative expectations.